# JQuery overlay wont work

Tags: jquery, overlay

I'm very new to JQuery (and HTML in general) and I'm trying to get a an overlay to show and play an embedded film when an image is clicked. However, the image isn't clickable and I can't see why.

Here's my code:

```
<style>
    .film_overlay {
     display:none;
     z-index:500;
     background-color:#d0d0d0;
     width:520;
     min-heigth:300;
     border:1px solid #666;
     -moz-box-shadow:0 0 90px 5px #000;
     -webkit-box-shadow:0 0 90px 5px #000;
 }
 .film_overlay .close {
     background-image:url(http://www.destinationfjallen.se/sites/destfjallen/files/close.png);
     position:absolute;
     right:-15px;
     top:-15px;
     cursor:pointer;
     height:35px;
     width:35px;
 }
</style>

<img class="karta" src="http://www.destinationfjallen.se/sites/destfjallen/files/film1.jpg" rel="#film"/>

<div class="film_overlay" id="#film">
     <iframe src="http://player.vimeo.com/video/54730694?title=0&amp;byline=0&amp;portrait=0&amp;autoplay=1" width="500" height="281" frameborder="0"webkitAllowFullScreen mozallowfullscreen allowFullScreen></iframe>
</div>

<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
   $("img[rel]").overlay();
});
</script>
```

I'm grateful for all the help I can get!

Comment: `.overlay()` is not a part of jQuery. are you using some plugin?

Comment: It's not? Oh I thought it was!I followed this guide:
http://jquerytools.org/demos/overlay/index.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.overlay()` is not a part of jQuery. It's a plugin found within the jQuery tools library. You'll have to include it. Add the following line to the `<head>` part of your page (after you load jQuery):

```
<script src="http://cdn.jquerytools.org/1.2.7/full/jquery.tools.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think $("img[rel]") is a correct selector.

If you want to select the image having a specific `rel` value you may try

```
$("img[rel=#film]")
```

By the way I would remove the `#` for your id `(id="film")`, not sure you could select with `$("##film")`

Moreover `rel` isn't a correct attribute for the `img` tag. See http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/struct/objects.html#edef-IMG

Comment: Just try `$("img").overlay();` to see if the problem comes from the selector. Btw did you import the correct library as stated by Yotam Omer?

Comment: `$("img[rel]")` means an `img` object that has a `rel` attribute. the value of `rel` is not relevant.

Comment: I changed so that the image lays inside a div, and the div is the selector. I also imported the library like Yotam Omer said, and now it works! Thank you both very much!

Answer (score 0):

You need to add script source in the head tag of your page as it is a plugin .The following link will help you understand more about Jquery Overlay

http://jquerytools.org/documentation/overlay/